# Are empty synchronized blocks optimized out by Java compiler?

Tags: java, locking, compiler-optimization

Suppose somewhere in my code I write an empty `synchronized` block:

```
synchronized(obj){
   //No code here
}
```

So as the synchronized block does not contain any code, will JIT compiler optimize that out by not locking on `obj` as it will be of no use?

Java compiler does similar tricks such as Lock coarsening but will this synchronized block be also optimized out?

**EDIT:**

As per the point made by assylias,

```
synchronized(new Object()){
   //empty block
}
```

will the JIT compiler now be able to optimize this out, since I am using an Object which doesn't escape my method?

Comment: @tbodt if he could he wouldn't ask... Please tell him how to "try it"

Comment: I just put that code in a file, decompiled the class file, and the synchronized block was still there, even though it was empty.

Comment: @tbodt that does not prove anything. It might be removed by the JIT. Another compiler/JVM might behave differently etc.

Comment: @Tala IMHO having understanding of what compiler does in background makes you much better programmer.

Comment: @tbodt Looking at bytecode *very rarely* proves anything. Just don't bother with it.

Comment: Narendra, I've edited your question so as not to sound like an answer (just satisfying the SO form).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This can't be optimized away on the basis of the Java Memory Model semantics. The lock acquisition-release operation *may* be replaced by something else, but even an empty `synchronized` block has consequences on the visibility of actions taken by other threads acquiring the same lock.

Specifically, there is a guarantee that *all write actions done by one thread before releasing the lock are visible to the other thread after it acquires the same lock*.

#### Regarding your EDIT

This is a very different case: a lock is obtained on an object which can be proved by *escape analysis* that no other thread will ever be able to fetch it. In this case it doesn't matter what the contents of the `synchronized` block are: the point is only in the lock used. The code can look as you posted it, or even like this:

```
Object o = new Object();
synchronized(o) { 
   // any operations you like, as long as they don't let o escape the method scope
}
```

This can be acted upon by the transformation known as *lock elision*: the JVM can pretend it never saw the `synchronized` block. This is because the JMM semantics refer only to the cases of acquiring *the one and the same lock*.

Comment: @assylias I will add that in the question too :) Nice point as in that case there will be no visibility guarantee too.

Comment: @assylias Your and my answers are becoming indistinguishable :)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I take that as a compliment!

Comment: So, if we use `synchronized(mutex){ }` where `mutex` is a shared variable (a field of a class), we can safely assume visibility guarantees provided by this locking, right? I mean, no `lock elision` happens

Comment: @Alupkers Either another thread takes the same lock and gets the guarantees, or it doesn't and doesn't get them. Whenever the JIT compiler can prove that it will be impossible for another thread to get the same lock, it can remove it from the machine code it outputs. If it cannot prove it, it will output the appropriate memory fence.